# macOS Big Sur python3 cannot import numpy due to polyfit error

Tags: python, macos, numpy, macos-big-sur, xcode-command-line-tools

**update from Jan 2021:** I performed a clean install of Big Sur in Jan 2021, and upgrade pip to latest version using `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip --user`, and installed `numpy` without issues, and without the error message below.

**original question from Nov 2020**

I'm using macOS big sur on 2019 macbook pro. I'm able to install numpy using `python3 -m pip install numpy --user`. Note I do *not* have brew; I'm just using the python3 from the Xcode command line tools. I've seen this error reported in many other places, but they all seem to use brew.

However, when I try to `import numpy as np`, I get the following error messsage.

```
Python(488,0x11700be00) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071565352960, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
Python(488,0x11700be00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
init_dgelsd failed init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xdavidliu/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

Answer (score 9):

The numpy installed by default in my question (and which caused the crash) was 1.19. I was able to use numpy with the following workaround:

```
python3 -m pip uninstall numpy
python3 -m pip install numpy==1.18.0 --user
```

Comment: I was still getting this error even though I apparently didn't have the malicious numpy version installed. I tried running the first command to uninstall numpy and got this:

```WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed.```